# Who holds the record for most dunks in a single playoff game?

Tags: basketball, records, postseason

Who holds the record for most dunks in a single postseason game?

This is not restricted to a single league.

Comment: I think you need to ask these sorts of questions restricted to a particular league or at least some level - they won’t be answerable when the correct answer is “80, in my high school league’s AAA playoffs” or whatever.